# multipart/form-data breaks bean resolution - JSF 2.2

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2

I am using javax-faces-2.2.1 on Tomcat 7.0 and am trying to get the file upload to work.

Adding h:inputFile throws an error saying the form needs to be multipart but the backing bean is resolved. Adding enctype="multipart/form-data throws an error saying that the bean is unreachable as the bean identifier resolves to null.

As I am using JSF 2.2 I understand that I do not need to define filters in web.xml and that I do not need to add commons-fileupload to lib

The relevant bits of the page are

```
    <h:html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<ui:composition template="/zuzztemplate.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="page-form" prependId="false" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

and

```
  <rich:tab name="Photos" >
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
      <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="field-label,field-value">
        <h:outputLabel for="caption" value="Caption:" styleClass="form-label" />
        <h:inputText id="caption" value="#{galleryBean.photoCaption}" size="50" />
      </h:panelGrid>
      <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{galleryBean.uploadFile}"/>
      <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{galleryBean.upload}"  ajax="false"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
  </rich:tab>
```

The backing bean is annotated with

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class GalleryBean extends BaseBean {
```

There is no form in the template and h:head and h:body are used

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Also your command button looks suspicious there with `ajax="false"`. I don't think that's a valid attribute for vanilla JSF components. Try the `<h:inputFile/>` outside of the richfaces tabpanel, by itself

Comment: I found the cause of this - it was not the JSF part at all but the Eclipse/Tomcat arrangement - I have been running my xhtml pages on the server via Eclipse and for some reason Eclipse stopped publishing the application. Using Clean Tomcat Work Directory solved the problem